Make TipView show its image on the left instead of on top
I Have a tipView that always shows the tip Image above the title (like a VStack) whereas all the tutorials I see have the image on the left as if in an HStack.
Portrait:

Landscape:

Edit: I am developing with
Xcode 15.4 and
iPhone 12 running iOS 17.5
note: The problem does not exist in the simulator on iPhone 15 or iPad so maybe it's just to do with the older device.
import SwiftUI
import TipKit

@main

struct TipTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TipTEST()
                .task {
                    try? Tips.resetDatastore()
                    try? Tips.configure([
                        .datastoreLocation(.applicationDefault)                    
                    ])
                }
        }
    }
}


struct TipTEST: View {
    
    let setTranslationLanguageTip = SetTranslationLanguageTip()
    var body: some View {
        TipView(setTranslationLanguageTip)
        
 // Same problem with a popover
//        Text("Tip view test")
//            .popoverTip(setTranslationLanguageTip)
    }
}



struct SetTranslationLanguageTip: Tip {
    static let translationSetEvent = Event(id: "translationSet")
    
    var title: Text {
        return Text("Set translation language")
    }
    
    var message: Text? {
        return Text("Placeholder tip message")
    }

    var image: Image? {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
    }
}


Can you please provide code of how you use the TipView?

I'm not sure we can make these changes with current TipKit versions....
